# Bootstrap 3 keyboard not reacting to default keyboard events

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, keyboard

Based on docs,
/javascript/#carousel

`keyboard    boolean     true`

When I try there demo (which is using default setting)

http://getbootstrap.com/examples/carousel/

Note: (Mac 10.9.5, Safari 7.1.3, Firefox 36.0.1)

**Safari,**
Never seems to respond to keyboard events.

**FireFox**
Works sometimes, but when it does work if I click on the bottom of screen, it will ignore future keyboard events.

I've tried using:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 $("#myCarousel").carousel({

     interval : false,

     pause: true,

     keyboard: true

 });

});
```

and that doesn't seem to help either.

Any suggestions? - Thanks,
R

## UPDATE

My Github issue has been closed with an explanation...
https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/16164

Comment: Did you take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15722372/3207406 ?

Comment: Actually, the answer just after looks even better: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21412486/3207406

Comment: Thanks for fast response.  I did research this for an hour or so... those links are for version 2 of Twitter Bootstrap I believe. I want to use the BUILT-IN feature of the latest Bootstrap 3.x  -   as one of those posts says * I know this is going to be implement in the next release, but for now I... * -

Answer (score 1):

The code given in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21412486/3207406) works perfectly with your [demo](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/carousel/)
Just add this code at the very end of the document :

```
<script>
$(document).bind('keyup', function(e) {
    if(e.which == 39){
        $('.carousel').carousel('next');
    }
    else if(e.which == 37){
        $('.carousel').carousel('prev');
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, Bootstrap on Github answered this as well, and closed my issue:

Comment: I still think, the Bootstrap demo, in Safari, doesn't respond to keyboard events, at least for me. http://getbootstrap.com/examples/carousel/  So some work is required to make it work.

Comment: If you want to correct the Bootstrap demo, I think StackOverflow is the wrong place to discuss about it.
If you want it to work on your own website, I think my answer works.